# Change second fragment based on choice in first fragment

Tags: android

I have three fragments in my activity. How can I change the content of the second fragment (chapter) based on what book I select?

[image: my app]

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs,container,false);
        bible_group = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.bible_group);

        bible_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId){

                    case R.id.genesis:
                    case R.id.exodus:
                    case R.id.leviticus:
                    case R.id.numbers:
                    case R.id.deuteronomy:
                    case R.id.joshua:
                    case R.id.judges:
                    case R.id.ruth:
                    case R.id.samuel1:
                    case R.id.samuel2:
                    case R.id.kings1:
                    case R.id.kings2:
                    case R.id.chronicles1:
                    case R.id.chronicles2:
                    case R.id.ezra:
                    case R.id.nehemiah:
                    case R.id.esther:
                    case R.id.job:
                    case R.id.psalm:
                    case R.id.proverbs:
                    case R.id.ecclesiastes:
                    case R.id.songofsolomon:
                    case R.id.isaiah:
                    case R.id.jeremiah:
                    case R.id.lament:
                    case R.id.ezek:
                    case R.id.dan:
                    case R.id.hosea:
                    case R.id.joel:
                    case R.id.amos:
                    case R.id.obadiah:
                    case R.id.jonah:
                    case R.id.micah:
                    case R.id.nahum:
                    case R.id.habakkuk:
                    case R.id.zephaniah:
                    case R.id.haggai:
                    case R.id.zechariah:
                    case R.id.malachi:
                    case R.id.matthew:
                    case R.id.mark:
                    case R.id.luke:
                    case R.id.john:
                    case R.id.acts:
                    case R.id.romans:
                    case R.id.corinths1:
                    case R.id.corinths2:
                    case R.id.galatians:
                    case R.id.ephesians:
                    case R.id.phili:
```

Comment: You could start at a similar example in the documentation.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

From Activity you can send data to Fragment with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("nameOfbook", "Genesis");
  //set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

EDIT : For show the fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
      .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
      .show(fragobj)
      .commit();
```

and to receive in fragment in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      String strtext=getArguments().getString("nameOfBook");

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

You can put another parameters in the bundle (author, description, etc ...)

Comment: Could you expand on that answer, please? How is the activity going to show the `Fragmentclass` object you made?

Comment: I edit my post now you can show the fragment

Comment: Sure, however it appears from the image that a ViewPager is being used, so I'm not sure this is the needed code

Comment: If you use a viewPager you need to create an adapter, you must follow a tutorial on viewPager, i can't explain all here

Comment: thanks Vaudey ,am using three fragments under that  one activity ,though i have not  got you properly ,like i want to establish a communication between the three fragments,in that when i select genesis it takes me to chapter select a chapter then it takes me to the verse which then opens up the scriptures.but then how can i change the content of each book i pick so that it displays different content for each item in the chapter fragment

Comment: I think that every line in your view are some textView, so you just have to do a textView1.setText("Chapter 1"); etc...
Because if you know the name of the book you know the number and the name of chapter